# How to use 2D GameObject array as a parameter in a c# function ( 2D unity game)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie at unity/c#, and i'm coding a 2D chess game using unity, and i'm having some trouble making functions.
I'm trying to setup a function that renders pieces on the board, but i can't seem to make it work.
I want to use 2D array as a third parameter in this function but I keep getting this error:
*error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject[,]'*.
This is my board class:

```
void Start()
{
    boardScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("BoardScript").GetComponent<Board>();
    spawn = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameController").GetComponent<SpawnPieces>();

    boardScript.createBoard();
}
```

This is one of my piece classes:

```
public void spawnQueen(int x, int y, GameObject[,] board)
{
    if (x == 3 && y == 0)
    {
        board[x, y] = Instantiate(whiteQueen, new Vector3(x * 4.49f, y * 4.49f, -1), Quaternion.identity);
    }
    else if (x == 3 && y == 7)
    {
        board[x, y] = Instantiate(blackQueen, new Vector3(x * 4.49f, y * 4.49f, -1), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

And this is the class that will render the pieces :

```
public void spawnPiece()
{
    boardScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("BoardScript").GetComponent<Board>();
    GameObject[,] boardArray = boardScript.board;

    rookScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("RookScript").GetComponent<RookScript>();
    pawnScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PawnScript").GetComponent<PawnScript>();
    kingScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("KingScript").GetComponent<KingScript>();
    bishopScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("BishopScript").GetComponent<BishopScript>();
    kinghtScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("knightScript").GetComponent<knightScript>();
    queenScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("QueenScript").GetComponent<QueenScript>();

    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {
            rookScript.spawnRook(x, y, boardArray[x, y]);
            pawnScript.spawnPawn(x, y, boardArray[x, y]);
            knightScript.spawnKnight(x, y, boardArray[x, y]);
            kingScript.spawnKing(x, y, boardArray[x, y]);
            queenScript.spawnQueen(x, y, boardArray[x, y]);
            bishopScript.spawnBishop(x, y, boardArray[x, y]);
        }
    }
}
```

As I have mentionned I am new to C#, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: well you want the array or an element of it as parameter? because currently you are passing the **element** at indices `[x,y]` .. not the entire array `boardArray` .... looks like a **TYPO** ?

Comment: in general instead of iterating over all the fields - knowing that most of them are empty anyway - and then for each tile check if it can be placed at certain positions ... why not rather somewhere store these positions in arrays and iterate these once?

Comment: It also looks like you are using tags a bit strange ... couldn't all of the components simply be attached to the board itself and after the first find you could simply `GetComponent` them all from the same GameObject?

Answer (score 1):

With the way you call your method you are passing an `element` of the boardArray instead of the whole array. Try calling the method like this:

```
bishopScript.spawnBishop(x, y, boardArray);
```

Notice the third argument is `boardArray` as opposed to `boardArray[x, y]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, now i can spawn all the pieces.